# How to copy columns from previous worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a simple question, but I am a amateur coder (at best) and cant figure out how to make this work.

I am creating a family budget and am trying to copy certain columns (H-AZ) from the previous worksheet to the next.

The reason I need to do this is that I am trying to copy a table that tracks our expenditures. I have the table formatted to isolate certain expenditures (gas, groceries, etc.) and to sum the values of the cells based on a descriptor located in another cell. This table will be constantly evolving as my families spending habits change.

Since this table will grow in complexity every month, I don't want to have to re enter all of the old formulas. I just want to enter the new formulas.

If any of this is too confusing, please let me know and I will try to clarify my problem.

Thanks for your help

Sincerely, 
Josiah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The formula is not get copied

```
Sub CopyColumnValue()

    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Columns("H:AZ").Copy
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Columns("H:AZ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked well. I took out the paste values because I wanted to save the formulas and not the values. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a PivotTable and a Calculated Field in which to store the formula. That way you just enter the Data(expenses) into a sheet every month and refresh the Pivotable to get the new calculated results. Bear in mind, pivots can do SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT and other totaling Built-in. So you won't need a Calculated Field for that..

Highlight the table data and click insert PivotTable. Search for Tutorials for Pivots online.
some suggestions:

- http://chandoo.org/wp/excel-tutorial/working-with-pivot-tables/
- http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel

Let me know how it goes, I'll refine my answer to point you and others in the right direction.
G